# Using p:inputNumber with BigDecimal and comma separator

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to use  with "," as a separator, regarding my locale settings. My main problem is, that the number(s) after the separator doesn't even get to the bean itself.

I already tried to add decimalSeparator="," and  to the  but nothing changed...

This cellEditor includes the editor and the output:

```
<p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText id="grossMoney" value="#{item.grossMoney}">
                        <f:convertNumber locale="hu"/>
                        <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="0"/>
                    </h:outputText>                        
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">                         
                    <p:inputNumber id="grossMoneyEdit" decimalSeparator="," value="#{item.grossMoney}" >
                        <f:convertNumber locale="hu"/>
                        <!-- <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="0"/> -->                        

                    </p:inputNumber>
                </f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
```

This is the bean method, where the setter doesn't get the value right:

```
public void setGrossMoney(BigDecimal grossMoney) {
    if (grossMoney != null && grossMoney != BigDecimal.ZERO) {

        if (vatRate == 0) {
            netUnitPrice = grossMoney;
        } else {
            netUnitPrice = grossMoney.divide(BigDecimal.ONE.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(vatRate).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100L))), 3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        }

    } else {
        netUnitPrice = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }
}
```

Expected result is simple: if I enter 100,5, it should be converted to BigDecimal and calculate with the correct value and on the output side it should be presented as 100,5 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are somehow specifying the same aspect in multiple ways: `converter`, `decimalSeparator`, `language`, multiple `converters` in a single `component`.

Primefaces `p:inputNumber` has a simple `lang`uage attribute - did you try that?

```
<p:inputNumber value="#{myBean.decimalVal}" lang="hu"/>
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.decimalVal}">
   <f:convertNumber locale="hu" />
</h:outputText>
```

You are also not setting the `grossMoney` field in your setter. Instead you do calculations of `netUnitPrice`. You should better do that in an action or (action/ajax)listener. Keep getters/setters trivial.